# Not able to open spark-shell with hdfs user using bash script

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to open spark-shell using bash script with "hdfs" user. The bash script is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u hdfs -H sh -c "cd /opt/project1"
/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/bin/spark-shell
echo "entered"
echo "executed"
```

It opens the spark-shell with root user instead of hdfs. Can anyone help me out, how to switch user to hdfs first and then open spark-shell.?

Comment: did you install spark using root user?

Comment: Yes.
 
I downloaded all the hadoop services (Spark, Kafka, zookeeper etc) through Ambari.

Comment: In that case you will have to grant permissions. Also set the path.